# Java JDBC Procedure Call

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, call, procedure

I have a oracle procedure that takes date as a parameter and gets called by two different Java web apps, within the procedure I extract the day using `to_char(date, 'd')` from the date passed. I am unable to find out why the day returned by one app is different from other. I am using same ojdbc driver for both of the apps. Does it have anything to do with machine env variable these apps are running at?

Thanks

Comment: I think you meant `to_char(date, 'd')` instead of `sysdate(date, 'd')`.

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of the procedure?

Comment: Thanks Adam, you are right. Basically I literally do to_char(date, 'd') and that's all.

Comment: Could you then add some examples of dates you have passed in and the values that have been returned?

Comment: Yo, Abidi. Your answer is answered by Vincent. I think you should mark his answer as the definitive one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to explicitly specify the timezone on both of your webapp containers by passing them the `-Duser.timezone="America/New_York"` VM argument (adjust per your timezone needs) when startingup them.

To address your comment, in the application level you could explicitly specify the desired timezone when calling your stored proc. For example:

```
CallableStatement statement = null;
Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = getYourConnection();
        Calendar dbCal = new GregorianCalendar(YOUR_DATABASE_TIMEZONE);

        String sql = "begin schema_name.package_name.stored_proc(var1=>?, " +
                "var2=>?); end;";

        statement = conn.prepareCall(sql);
        statement.setInt(1, something);
        statement.setTimestamp(2, yourDate.getTime(), dbCal);

        statement.execute();

        conn.commit();

    } finally {
        if (statement!=null) statement.close();
        if (conn!=null) conn.close();
    }
```

Comment: I found the difference in Locale settings on both machines, one of them dint have LANGUAGE set at all whereas both have LANG set to LANG=en_GB.UTF-8. @Dimitrisli I think that will do the job but is there anyway to change it at context level rather than at tomcat level. I mean if I could set it through context.xml (or something) just for an app?

Comment: @Abidi You can specify the timezone you wish to save the date in the DB during your jdbc call to the stored proc, I've edited the comment with an example.

Comment: Thanks Dimitrisli, I still don't understand why same Java code running in two different webapps with both tomcats using the same JVM parameters would make Oracle to calculate days from a date differently.

Comment: I would suggest first make sure where exactly this inconsistency is coming from. Debug both of your apps and inspect the date just prior reaching the stored proc to see whether they are different or not. If they are then the difference is coming from the app somewhere so debug both from the beginning more closely to see exactly where the date differentiates.

Answer (score 2):

this is because the first day of the week is not the same in all countries, for example in Europe the first day of the week is Monday while in the US it is Sunday. Consider:

```
SQL> select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_TERRITORY';

PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
NLS_TERRITORY                  AMERICA

SQL> select to_char(date '2010-12-07', 'D') from dual;

TO_CHAR(DATE'2010-12-07','D')
-----------------------------
3

SQL> alter session set nls_territory=FRANCE;

Session altered

SQL> select to_char(date '2010-12-07', 'D') from dual;

TO_CHAR(DATE'2010-12-07','D')
-----------------------------
2
```

Set the session parameter NLS_TERRITORY at the beginning of the procedure if it depends on it.

Comment: Thats right I agree, but both apps are accessing the very same database, schema and procedure and the outcome of days is different.

Comment: @abidi: this is a session parameter: it is set by the client, not the DB.

Answer (score 1):

try to check the default locale in JAVA/Oracle in both the applications.

I think that it may depend on the default locale set in JAVA.

Comment: Nowhere in my web apps I set the locale explicitly. The default one in Oracle is American.